# beamer, bidi, hebrew, xelatex, equation bracket problem

Tags: beamer, equations, xetex, hebrew

the following minimal example works well with xelatex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
\setRL
 שלום  
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:hebrew-math:1}
\int 
\end{equation}
 \end{document}
```

however, the following does not

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \setR 
  שלום
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:hebrew-math:1}
  \int 
  \end{equation}
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

the brackets of the numbered equations are wrong.
Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?
regards
Uwe Brauer

Comment: Did you mean to write `\setRL` rather than `\setR` in the `beamer` MWE (minimum working example)?

Comment: looks okay for me in a current texlive, can you show your log-file?

Comment: \should be \setRL

Comment: how can I attach the log file? when I copy it, its refused too long

Comment: Your system is from 2015 and so quite outdated, we have 2019.

Comment: right, fortunately I downloaded just the latest bidi package version and this solves the problem. I know I should upgrade texlive, but I don't have the bandwidth right now.